# Blurry/Grainy/Pixelated text in IE7/8/9

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm having an issue where certain bits of text are appearing very blurry/grainy/pixelated in versions of IE (7,8,9, not 10). Any idea what might be causing it?

I'm pulling in Myriad Pro from fonts.com, but I still get the issue if I switch it back to basic Arial.

See below for how the text is displaying.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the following styles to your CSS:

```
text-shadow: none;
filter: none;
```

If this doesn't work, try wrapping your text with a tag other than headings (h1 - h6), like a `div` for example.

This did the trick for me!

Comment: I had a rogue filter that was affecting the text, so the filter: none pointed me in the right direction!